# CSS or CS3 body shadow implementation

Tags: css

Can you help me on this one?

Just want to ask on how to implement this on css/css3 or any possible way to have an shadow background on a body element. Please [see this link](http://marskie.com/body-shadow.jpg) for you to see what i mean.

Thanks all

Comment: Did you try and solve this problem yourself before asking here? It should take less than 5 minutes to find the CSS `box-shadow` property.

Comment: If you just tell me what to do maybe you can help someone like me for not having an idea on this one. It's just a choice to help someone. By the way error404 just gave me a good answer. 

What is the purpose of having a stackoverflow if you people will help someone like me a "noob" like me on this cool way of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an inset box-shadow to the HTML tag:

```
html {   
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}​
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/F6p8c/1/

The first two values define the x-axis and y-axis offsets respectively. The third value is the size of the shadow. The hex value is the colour (obviously).